# Spring Boot - The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values but expect only one

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I read all posts on StackOverflow on this topic but did not find answer as they all are about difference scenario than mine.

My spring boot API uses Spring Security and is accessed by Angular client.

The Angular client can query various endpoints to which my API adds "`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`" as "**http://localhost:4200**" using `CorsConfiguration` `setAllowedOrigins` method.  I get responses as expected including this header, so all good.

However, one of the endpoints **calls another API**.  That API also has its own "`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`" set to "*".

If my client queries this endpoint, I get following error:

"**CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:4200, *', but only one is allowed.**"

So, the 2nd API adds this header with * in it, then my API also adds "http://localhost:4200" and I end up with double entry in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header like "http://localhost:4200, *".

I would like to fix this issue but I dont know how.

My API security configuration is adding CorsConfiguration like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(...);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .and()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
}
```

and all my controllers are annotated with:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
```

Above, I call `setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"))` to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in my API.

All endpoints in my API work as expected except one endpoint which calls another API.  That API also sets 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to "*" which then ends up back in my API resulting in double values:  "http://localhost:4200" and "*" in 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

Here is my Controller and Service that is failing.  As said, all others (which do not call another API) are working fine.

Below is my controller, it calls my service provided below.  The service call succeeds and returns response.  However, once this response is sent to the client, I get the above error.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/wagen")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class WagenController {

    public WagenController(WagenService service) {
          wagenService = service;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<WagenResponse> getWagen(@RequestBody WagenRequest wagenRequest, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ResponseEntity<WagenResponse> wagenResponse = wagenService.getWagen(wagenRequest, httpHeaders);
        return wagenResponse;
    }
}
```

Here is my service.  It uses restTemplate to make a call to the other API.  All this works fine:

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<WagenResponse> getWagen(WagenRequest wagenRequest, HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
    List<String> authHeader = httpHeaders.get("authorization");
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    // add BasicAuth for the other API before calling it in 
    //  below restTemplate call
    headers.add("Authorization", authHeader.get(0)); 

    HttpEntity<WagenRequest> request = new HttpEntity<WagenRequest>(wagenRequest, headers);
    ResponseEntity<WagenResponse> wagenResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, WagenResponse.class);
    return wagenResponse;
}
```

How do I fix this issue so that I dont have 2nd entry in 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'?  Or some other way?

I dont have a way to change what other API is sending to me.

Here is the screenshot of network tab in dev tools and error shown in console (This works fine in PostMan).  Interestingly, Firefox dev tools show that the :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried not reusing the same headers when calling the second api? I note that you haven't shared the code that interacts with that other API, so it's hard to discuss specifics.

Comment: Thank you Roddy, I update post to provide that information

Comment: the HttpHeaders you pass to that getWagen method should be different headers than your own inbound request headers. then the cors header that's added by the api will not be added to the headers you will be returning to your caller.

Comment: Thanks @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas , I wouldn't mind if you elaborate a bit but if I understand you correctly, the `HttpHeaders` I receive in `getWagen()` carry few headers out of which I remove all except the 'authorization' (BasicAuth) header the other API needs.  This all works fine, I get response back but when my controller sends it back to client, I get that error.  In PostMan, it all works

Comment: Because you're using the same object. Create a new set of HTTP Headers so that the Wagen api doesn't contaminate the headers that you're going to be returning to _your_ client.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas  But I am doing that.  See above in the service method.  I create brand new HttpHeaders and add only the BasicAuth needed for the 2nd API.  it is not the same object.  I also provided screenshot showing what happens in Networking tab and Console tab of Firefox dev tools.  Thank you

Comment: But you're returning `wagenResponse` _which includes those other headers_. Don't do that. Take the body out of `wagenResponse`, and build your responseEntity from it. ReponseEntity as returned by `getWagen` includes that CORS header from the wagen api. You only want the body from that response, not anything else in there.

Comment: Ahhhh, gotcha.  Yes, that's the problem.  Thank you for your help

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Would you mind posting your suggestion as an answer and I will accept it.  I am confirming that your suggestion has solved my problem.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in how you're calling that other API that's the source of the extra CORS header.

In your endpoint, reproduced here, you call `getWagen` and retrieve a `ResponseEntity` as a response:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<WagenResponse> getWagen(@RequestBody WagenRequest wagenRequest, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders, HttpServletResponse response) {
  ResponseEntity<WagenResponse> wagenResponse = wagenService.getWagen(wagenRequest, httpHeaders);
  return wagenResponse;
}
```

The problem is in what you're doing with the response from the Wagen API.

A `ResponseEntity` is the *whole* response from the other API -- including the headers. If you put a breakpoint on that `return` statement, you'll be able to explore the `wagenResponse` object and see that the headers include the `"*"` CORS header as returned by the other API.

By returning the `ResponseEntity` as-is, you're going to be returning those API headers as well. Then the decorators and annotations you have in your app will add your CORS headers *on top* of those returned by the Wagen API ... hence your problem.

When you get back the `ResponseEntity<WagenResponse>` from the `getWagen` method, you need to pick out the bits you actually want -- the body, the status, any non-CORS headers -- and then generate a *new* `ResponseEntity` to return to the caller.

Comment: Much appreciated.  That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to Java Spring Boot but here's how I handled CORS:
Under main():

```java
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
        }
    };
}
```

I hope it can help you!

Comment: hey and thanks.  I am already handing CORS and it works great.  The issue is specific to calling another api that also returns CORS.  but thanks for response

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  My CORS settings were correct as I thought.  I found solution thanks to the help of @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas above.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

just add this .

```
 @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    if (HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name().equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
}
```